# $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is analytic function and $z_0 \in \mathbb C$,$f(r)=z_0 \forall r \in \mathbb Q\cap[1,2]$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

$f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is analytic function and $z_0 \in \mathbb C$, I am investigating the character of $f$, when

> > $f(\frac{1}{n})=z_0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$
>
> and if,
>
> $f(r)=z_0 \forall r \in \mathbb  Q\cap[1,2]$
>
> and if,
>
> $f(n)=z_0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$,

For theirst two cases what I am doing is that,

> > define $g(z):=f(z)-z_0$, the the set of zeros of $g$ has limit point $0$ (as $\frac{1}{n} \to 0 ,\text as. n \to \infty$)which belongs to domain of $g$,similarly for $r_n$ be rational sequence in $[1,2]$ will have limit point =$1,2$ as $[1,2]$closed. Then applying Identity mapping theorem $g=0$ identically in $\mathbb C$,
>
> i.e. $f(z)=z_0$
>
> Now for this case $f(n)=z_0 \forall n \in \mathbb N$, can we conclude that $f$ is constant $z_0?$
>
> Can $f$ take the value $z_0$ for finitely many points in the set {$\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb N$}?

Comment: The last sentence is not clear.

Comment: edited..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for the first two cases is correct.
There are lots of entire functions $f$ with $f(n)=z_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ . One example is $z_0+\sin (\pi z)$.

A general fact: if $S$ is any set of complex numbers with no limit points and $z_s$ is a  complex number for each $s \in S$ then there is an entire function $f$ such that $f(s)=z_s$ for all $s \in S$. In particular this holds for a finite set $S$.

Comment: More generally, $f(z)=z_0+g(z)\sin (\pi z)$ for any entire function $g$.

Comment: @tret I have edited the answer to include an answer to the last part.

Comment: I am stunned by the instant downvote I got when I posted the answer. Can the downvoter kindly explain?